# Output filename from input in bash

Tags: bash, input, output, filenames

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FASTQFILES=~/Programs/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/DB_files/*.fastq
FASTAFILES=~/Programs/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/DB_files/*.fasta
clear
for file in $FASTQFILES
do cat $FASTQFILES | perl -e '$i=0;while(<>){if(/^\@/&&$i==0){s/^\@/\>/;print;}elsif($i==1){print;$i=-3}$i++;}' > ~/Programs/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/DB_files/"${FASTQFILES%.*}.fasta"
mv $FASTAFILES ~/Programs/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/db/

done
```

I'm trying it to grab the files defined in `$FASTQFILES`, do the `.fastq` to `.fasta` conversion, name the output with the same filename of the input, and move it to a new folder. E.g., `~/./DB_files/HELLO.fastq` should give a converted `~/./db/HELLO.fasta`

The problem is that the output of the conversion is a properly formatted hidden file called `.fasta` in the first folder instead of the expected one named `HELLO.fasta`. So there is nothing to `mv`. I think I'm messing up in the `${FASTQFILES%.*}.fasta` argument but I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems:

1. One part of your trouble is that you use `cat $FASTQFILES` instead of `cat $file`.
2. You also need to fix the I/O redirection at the end of that line to `> ~/Programs/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/DB_files/"${file%.fastq}.fasta"`.
3. The `mv` command needs to be executed outside the loop.

In fact, when processing a single file at a time, you don't need to use `cat` at all ([UUOC](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) — Useless Use Of Cat).  Simply provide `"$file"` as an argument to the Perl script.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Below is how I solved it using your suggestions. It might have been more elegant, but it works...

`#!/bin/bash
FASTQFILES=~/Programss/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/DB_files/*.fastq
FASTAFILES=~/Programss/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/DB_files/*.fasta
clear
for file1 in $FASTQFILES
do  <$file1 perl -e '$i=0;while(<>){if(/^\@/&&$i==0){s/^\@/\>/;print;}elsif($i==1){print;$i=-3}$i++;}' > "${file1%.fastq}.fasta"
done
for file2 in $FASTAFILES
do mv $file2 ~/Programss/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/db/
done`

Comment: Fair enough; you can redirect input to Perl too, as you did.  You don't need the loop around the `mv` command; it will move multiple files at once: `mv $FASTAFILES ~/Programss/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/db/`.  However, the loop will work.  There can't be any spaces in the file names for the script to work.